# Installshield installer size

Tags: installshield-2010

I've been asked to make a simple installer with Installshield 2010 Professional. The combine size of the files to be installed is about 2 megs, but the resulting installer is about 5 megs. I would like to know if there is a way to tweak the installshield project so I can have a smaller installer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. Those extra 3mb are InstallShield's code for installing your files.

You could zip the compiled installer into a compressed, [self extracting archive](http://www.winzip.com/prodpagese.htm), perhaps, if you simply want to reduce the size of the installer on disk. Furthermore, it looks like WinZip itself supports simple file installations if you don't need the advanced logic that InstallShield provides.

Comment: Yeap, I've been looking around and it seems there is no way to slim down the installer. But the size of the installer depends on the type of project you choose. Thanks!